Live Activity not showing up - React native
I have a React Native project and I'm trying to start a live activity.
The activity.id is printed as expected, but the live activity is not showing on either simulator or a physical device.
The Preview in Xcode looks fine.
Both the widget and the app are targeting iOS 17.
I've not included any images, only mock data.
Any ideas on what the problem might be?
func startLiveActivity() {
  if !ActivityAuthorizationInfo().areActivitiesEnabled {
    return
  }

  let attributes = RouxWidgetAttributes()
  let initialState = RouxWidgetAttributes.ContentState(...) // Props redacted for brevity
  let content = ActivityContent(state: initialState, staleDate: nil)

  do {
    let activity = try Activity.request(
      attributes: attributes,
      content: content,
      pushType: nil
    )
    print(activity.id)
  } catch {
    print("error showing live activity")
  }
}

struct RouxWidgetLiveActivity: Widget {
  var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
    ActivityConfiguration(for: RouxWidgetAttributes.self) { context in
      VStack {
        Text("\(context.state.title)")
      }
      .activityBackgroundTint(Color.white)
      .activitySystemActionForegroundColor(Color.black)

    } dynamicIsland: { context in
      DynamicIsland {
        DynamicIslandExpandedRegion(.bottom) {
          Text("\(context.state.title)")
        }
      } compactLeading: {
        Text("\(context.state.icon)")
      } compactTrailing: {
        Text("")
      } minimal: {
        Text(context.state.icon)
      }
      .widgetURL(URL(string: "http://www.apple.com"))
      .keylineTint(Color.red)
    }
  }
}


Updating to MacOS Sanoma 14.6.1 made it work, magically.
